# Desktop clock widget or application for several places

Tags: windows-xp, date-time, desktop-gadget

... i.e. I need a little clock application which floats on the desktop, and shows time. Only I need several clocks (three to be exact) for 3 time zones.

Anyone know of such an app?

Comment: Which OS, any preferred platform (desktop widgets for Windows, etc)?

Comment: @Gnoupi - darn. Always forget.

Comment: @Idigas - any preference on the "package"? Should it be a single program, or can it be a part of a bigger thing (for example Google/Yahoo widget bars)? Free or to pay for?

Comment: That's a good point, I'd suspect most of the sidebar (desktopSidebar, Google Desktop and so on) would have what you are after.  Problem is that they would be quite large for just a clock...

Comment: @Gnoupi - don't care really. Some of my dear friends are currently away in different time zones, and I just need something to help me avoid thinking when should I call them.

Answer (score 2):

Which OS is a big question as this is an easy one for both Windows 7 and Vista.  In both these operating systems you can simply add more clock gadgets to the desktop/sidebar and set each one to a different timezone (using the little spanner icon beside the gadget) and each one should remember its own settings, at least it does on my Vista machine and I'm pretty sure it does on my Win7 machine too.

-=EDIT=-

For WinXP [ZoneTick](http://zonetick.com/) (payware) or [Symmtime](http://www.symmetricom.com/resources/downloads/symmtime/) (freeware) look like interesting alternatives...

Oooh, found one that I'd probably use if I needed it: [Microsoft TimeZones](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=bff59fcf-3148-40b8-a286-fe7274f6e4d8&displaylang=en)... which has a picture and description [here](http://adeelkhan.com/blog/2007/01/31/microsoft-time-zone/).

Comment: I regularly forget to add that to the question - WinXP in this case.

Comment: Just found a couple of WinXP alternatives...